# Java exception error on main

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Hi guys im trying to make a average calculator (I'm learning java now), everything works fine except 1 thing. 
Here is my code:

```
package projects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class average {
    public static void main (String[]args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("/////////////////////////////////");
        System.out.println("///     Average Calculator     ///");
        System.out.println("/////////////////////////////////");
        System.out.println("How many numbers: ");
        int totalnumbers = sc.nextInt();
        int average = 0;
        int[] list;
        list = new int [totalnumbers];
        for(int X = 1 ; X <= totalnumbers ; X++){
            System.out.println("Please choose number " + X +": ");
            list[X] = sc.nextInt();
            average+=list[X];   


        }
        System.out.println("Your average is:" + (average/totalnumbers));

        sc.close();
    }

}
```

i cant figure out whats wrong but when its supposed to give me the average, it gives me this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at projects.average.main(average.java:19)

Comment: What does _array index out of bounds_ mean to you?

Comment: Think about how many iterations are going through your loop

Comment: Regarding your probable next question: you'll need to cast one of the division operands to a double to get a precise result: `double preciseAverage = ((double) sum) / totalNumbers;`. You shouldn't name `average`a variable that doesn't hold the average, but the sum of the numbers.

Comment: It's clearly stated as `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Array indexing goes from 0 to N-1.**

The runtime exception occurs when you attempt to access `list[X]` with `x == totalnumbers`.

---

Change this:

```
for(int X = 1 ; X <= totalnumbers ; X++){
    System.out.println("Please choose number " + X +": ");
    list[X] = sc.nextInt();
    average+=list[X];
```

To this:

```
for(int X = 0 ; X < totalnumbers ; X++){
    System.out.println("Please choose number " + (X+1) +": ");
    list[X] = sc.nextInt();
    average+=list[X];
```

Answer (score 1):

An array of `totalnumbers` items starts with index 0 and ends in index `totalnumbers-1`.
Your X iterates from 1 to `totalnumbers`, hence the exception when X reaches `totalnumbers`.